# Ignore field of field when serializing

Tags: jackson

If I have two classes with relations:

```
class A {
  long id;
  B b;
}

class B {
  long id;
  int property;
}
```

My question is: when serializing A, I hope to get only b's id, instead of the entire b object.  However, I don't want this to impact the serialization of B itself.  In other words, when serializing an instance of class B, the result should contain both id and property.

Any idea how this can be done with Jackson?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@JsonIgnoreProperties`.  The annotation is commonly used at the class level but it applies to properties as well.  when applied to property, it is used to ignore properties inside the annotated property.
.
here is my test class

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    B b = new B();
    b.id = 2L;
    b.property = 3;
    A a = new A();
    a.id = 1L;
    a.b = b;

    try {
        System.out.println("B:");
        System.out.println( mapper.writeValueAsString(b));
        System.out.println("A:");
        System.out.println( mapper.writeValueAsString(a));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}

public static class A {
    public long id;
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("property")
    public B b;
}

public static class B {
    public long id;
    public int property;
}
```

Output:

```
B:
{"id":2,"property":3}
A:
{"id":1,"b":{"id":2}}
```